# Selected file disappears after validation of other fields

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using a `<rich:tabpanel>` with 3 tabs. In the 2nd tab I have 3 `<rich:fileUpload>` components. All the 3 fields are mandatory. Hence I perform validation in the backing bean on submit of the contents in the page.

If I select a file in one of the file upload components and leave other 2 empty, then I get the validation messages for the 2 empty components as expected. However the first component is also re-rendered and is not retaining the selected file, even though the file contents are still stored in the property of the backing bean.

How can I retain the selected file on re-render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do not re-render the input fields itself, but only the holder(s) of the validation messages. You can do that with `<a4j:commandButton>` wherein you specify the IDs of the message component(s) in the `reRender` attribute (I am assuming that you're using RichFaces 3.3, not 4.0, as it's not by default possible to have a single file selection for file upload in the current 4.0).

Note that you don't need to validate for requireness in the action method. Just setting `required="true"` on the input component(s) is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. Big Fan :) Does this work for rich:fileUpload as well? I will try again.I am not doing to any specific re-rendering. I have a <h:commandbutton> which I use to submit and once I submit the new component is appearing.Thanks once again for your valuable time.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, as you were using RichFaces, I expected that you were using `<a4j:commandButton>` which does an Ajax submit and re-render. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Hi - Tried using a4j:commandButton inside <h:form>, but still the entire page seems to be refreshed instead of the components that I set to re-render. required=true also doesn't seem to work with rich:fileUpload component.

Comment: I am so sorry for wasting  your time, stupid me - I returned the control to a page than setting null on validation failure. But the error message is not getting displayed now :(

Comment: Works now. I had used a4g:region wrapping fileupload components and message components - replaced it with h:outputtext.Thanks BalusC. However required="true" doesn't seem to work with rich:fileUpload.